# File or module level 'feature' possible?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Some optimizations/algorithms make code considerably less readable, so it's useful to keep the ability to disable the complex-and-unwieldily functionality within a file/module so any errors introduced when modifying this code can be quickly tested against the simple code.

Currently using `const USE_SOME_FEATURE: bool = true;` seems a reasonable way, but makes the code read a little strangely, since `USE_SOME_FEATURE` is being used like an `ifdef` in C.

For instance, clippy wants you to write:

```
if foo {
    { ..other code.. }
} else {
    // final case
    if USE_SOME_FEATURE {
        { ..fancy_code.. }
    } else {
        { ..simple_code.. }
    }
}
```

As:

```
if foo {
    { ..other code.. }
} else if USE_SOME_FEATURE {
    // final case
    { ..fancy_code.. }
} else {
    // final case
    { ..simple_code.. }
}
```

Which IMHO hurts readability, and can be ignored - but is caused by using a boolean where a `feature` might make more sense.

Is there a way to expose a feature within a file without having it listed in the crate?
*(since this is only for internal debugging and testing changes to code)*.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think clippy is absolutely in the wrong to complain about this; sometimes nested ifs are easier to read than an `else if` chain. If you're primarily concerned about a clean bill of health from clippy, I'd look for some way to turn off this lint (probably just for this instance).

Comment: I went looking and there is an [issue](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/issues/798) to disable this lint when there is a comment in the outer `else`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a build script to create new cfg conditions. Use `println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=whatever")` in the build script, and then you can use `#[cfg(whatever)]` on your functions and statements.